# SystemVerilog: Automatic variables cannot have non-blocking assignments appearing for static reg

Tags: static, system-verilog, modelsim, quartus

I start getting this error after I actually make a register static.

This complies fine in Quartus:

```
task InitAutoRefresh;

       reg [$clog2(AUTOREFRESH_CLOCKS):0] AutoRefreshCounter = 0;

       AutoRefreshCounter <= AutoRefreshCounter + 1;
       InitState <= (AutoRefreshCounter < AUTOREFRESH_CLOCKS) ? InitState : InitState + 1;       

       InitCmd <= (AutoRefreshCounter == 0) ? CMD_AR : CMD_NOP;

endtask
```

But Modelsim gives me this error:

```
# ** Error (suppressible): C:/projects/Camera-RAM-VGA/Ram.sv(137): (vlog-2244) Variable 'AutoRefreshCounter' is implicitly static. You must either explicitly declare it as static or automatic
# or remove the initialization in the declaration of variable.
```

Now when I add `static` in front of `reg [$clog2(AUTOREFRESH_CLOCKS):0] AutoRefreshCounter = 0;` Quartus gives me this error (which looks to be the opposite of my change):

```
Error (10959): SystemVerilog error at Ram.sv(139): illegal assignment - automatic variables can't have non-blocking assignments
```

And this points to the register that I've just added the `static` keyword for!

The only possible explanation I can think of is that when I add `static` to this single `reg` it starts treating other regs as `automatic`, but then the line number in the error message is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply move the declaration of `AutoRefreshCounter` outside of the task. Then it is clear that the variable is to be initialized only once at time 0. (That is the reason for the "Implicitly static" error  message in the first place).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing for now. I wanted to keep it inside the task for code re-used. I'm a newbie and Verilog is giving me a hard time with my attempts of code re-use (like I would do in procedural programming)